# Dynamic binding of JsonProperty during deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, reflection, jackson

I'm wondering if there is any legit way to dynamically allocate name of JsonProperty so I would change it over time when needed ? With that being said I mean having :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Record
{
    public String Name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class QueryResult<T>
    {
       public List<T> records;
    }

    public static class QueryResultRecord extends QueryResult<Record>
    {
    }
}
```

Like above, I have a property Name, which by default will be named "Name" like this:

```
[
  {
    Name: "Test",
  },
  {
     Name: "test",
  },
]
```

Even though I have flexibility to use **@JsonProperty("name")** that's not a solution. What I am after is changing it multiple times when needed as I have some parameterized query which relies on it. So I would like to have **Name, FirstName, LastName** and so on. Is refletion api the right thing to use it here ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest legit way is to write custom [`AnnotationIntrospector`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.html):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;

public class MyJacksonAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated a) {
        PropertyName pn = super.findNameForSerialization(a);
        if (pn.getSimpleName().equals("Name")) {
            return pn.withSimpleName("LastName");  // set property name to your heart's content...
        }
        return pn;
    }
}
```

and then pass it to the jackson mapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new MyJacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
Record r1 = new Record();
mapper.writeValue(System.out, r1);
```

Note: the same introspector is used during deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any simple way to do it but you can use a custom `JsonSerializer` and implement your logic in it :

```
// Record class
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Record {

    protected String name;

    public Record(String name) {
        this.name = Name;
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

```
// RecordJsonSerializer class
public static class RecordJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Record> {

    private static final String[] NAMES = new String[]{
        "Name",
        "FirstName"
        // ...
    };

    protected int idx;

    public RecordJsonSerializer() {
        idx = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Record r, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jg.writeStartObject();
        jg.writeObjectField(NAMES[idx++], r.name); // Change the field name
        jg.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

---

```
// Use case
Record[] records = new Record[]{
    new Record("r0"),
    new Record("r1")
};

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .registerModule(
        new SimpleModule("Record")
        .addSerializer(Record.class, new RecordJsonSerializer())); // Register the serializer instance

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(records));
```

The output of this is: `[{"Name":"r0"},{"FirstName":"r1"}]`

Of course you must change the logic to define the property name to use when serializing the object (mine will crash with 3 records but it's just a simple example).